# Meteor "meteor run iOS" Unable to fetch platform ios: undefined

Tags: meteor

When I try to run `meteor run iOS`

I get this error:

> .meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/cordova-scripts/cordova.sh
>       Unable to fetch platform ios: undefined

I can't figure out why.
I have added the device iOS to the meteor project.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the iOS platform is missing.

Make sure you run `meteor add-platform ios` in your project directory

Comment: I have added iOS platform. When I try to run that command again it tells me that it is already installed. But I still get the above error.

Comment: Did you also add the sdk?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem after updating to the latest version of Meteor (1.1.0.2).  I was able to get my android emulator up and running by deleting `~/.meteor/android_bundle`.  Then I had to reinstall the android sdk with `meteor install-sdk android`.  I will admit that reinstalling the Cordova plugins for my app took a long time (~10 minutes) but that appears to only happen the first time that you run the application on the emulator.